# Error while trying to deploy to Google App Engine: max instances limit

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy a new version of my app on Google App Engine, but it fails with this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: You may not have more than 32 total max instances in your project.
```

I am surprised because the configuration file mentions 1 for max instances:

```
runtime: nodejs18
service: staging
instance_class: B1
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
  idle_timeout: 5m
```

The full trace:

```
gcloud app deploy --project=abc123 app.staging.yaml
Services to deploy:

descriptor:                  [<redacted>/gae-payload/app.staging.yaml]
source:                      [<redacted>/gae-payload]
target project:              [spfblogcollection]
target service:              [staging]
target version:              [20230517t155800]
target url:                  [https://staging-dot-<redacted>.ey.r.appspot.com]
target service account:      [<redacted>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com]


Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y

Beginning deployment of service [staging]...
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Uploading 1 file to Google Cloud Storage                 ═╣
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
File upload done.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: You may not have more than 32 total max instances in your project.
```

gcloud version:

```
Google Cloud SDK 431.0.0
alpha 2023.05.12
beta 2023.05.12
bq 2.0.92
bundled-python3-unix 3.9.16
cloud-datastore-emulator 2.3.0
core 2023.05.12
gcloud-crc32c 1.0.0
gsutil 5.23
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to delete old unused version from App Engine through the console, because these versions seem to count toward the project-level max instances even if not used anymore. It makes sense but I was surprised.

Otherwise, in case that may help someone, it seems that deploying with automatic scaling works:

```
runtime: nodejs18
service: staging
instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
```

Comment: I face the same problem that never encountered before. Is this "ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: You may not have more than 32 total max instances in your project." possibly inherited from recent upgrade of App Engine? 

Thanks for both answers provided above. For earlier, since ever I have yet to deploy first version to App Engine, therefore the solution is not applicable to me. Meantime, later solution is not working. Can you advise further?

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me: here are the steps:

1. Go to google cloud project ->
2. App Engine> services>
3. Here you will see default| staging | development | Production|

along with there versions-> click on which you are trying to deploy

4. Delete older versions that does not have any traffic allocation(0%)
5. Re deploy using `gcloud app deploy`

Give a upvote if you find it Useful! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Google Cloud Dashboard, then choose App Engine. On the left menu choose Versions and delete the old unused versions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, neither the `automatic_scaling` or `basic_scalling` section properties in the `app.yaml` did solve my problem. I provide the configuration that makes it work.

```
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Google has enforced a max instance limit per project of 32 for projects for certain projects in order to prevent abuse. When customers exceed this limit, they will see the error "You may not have more than %d total max instances in your project." during deployment. This limit would apply to manually scaled instances as well as max_instance limit for automatic/basic scaling.

Change max_instance to 32 and it worked for me